# Press Default Camera App Capture button programatically like in selfie stick Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

i am making an app in which i want to capture image in default camera app without pressing capture button.i also tired this but it just open camera app.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: You can try Camera 2 API check this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Comment: ok thanks 
i more question can you tell me please how i can toggle notification panel.
i tried performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS).But it just open notification panel but i want to toggle it if it is already opened then close it if closed then open.thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i am making an app in which i want to capture image in default camera app without pressing capture button

That is impractical, sorry.

First, there is no single "default camera app". There are ~2 billion Android devices in use, spanning thousands of models. Those models ship with hundreds of "default camera apps".

Second, there is no requirement for a camera app to have a capture button. Some might take a picture by other means. Even for those that have a capture button, there is no requirement for it to have anything in common with capture buttons in other camera apps.

Third, outside of accessibility services and rooted devices, an app cannot fake user input into another app.

You are welcome to write your own camera app, using the camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`), and come up with your own trigger for when a picture should be taken.

Comment: ok thanks i more question can you tell me please how i can toggle notification panel. i tried performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS).But it just open notification panel but i want to toggle it if it is already opened then close it if closed then open.thanks

Comment: @AliAsjad: I have no idea. Honestly, I hope that it is not possible. Regardless, please ask that as a separate Stack Overflow question.